# C# function with required return value

Tags: c#, function, return-value

Is there a way to write a function that requires that who uses it to get the return value?

For example. this will be throw an error:

```
public int MustUseReturnValueFN() {
   return 1;
}

private void main() {
   MustUseReturnValueFN(); // Error
   int a = MustUseReturnValueFN(); // Not Error
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here. You using `int` as a _return type_ you are not handling the return value in your `MustUseReturnValueFN(); // Error` line.

Comment: I don't believe so.  The value will be returned regardless of whether or not the caller does anything with it.

Comment: @SonerGönül - I think OP is looking for a way to make the function error if the caller doesn't do anything with the return value.  Don't know why they want to do that though (if I read the question right).

Comment: Would you care to explain _why_ you need this? What is your scenario/purpose?

Comment: I think there should not be any error instead editor give you  warning or suggestion as you are not using the returned value.

Comment: @inin you need code analysis tools. There no better ways I guess.

Comment: @Tim, you right (sorry if the question doesn't wrote clarity(

Comment: Have you given some thought to using an out parameter rather? Or a ref parameter? [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) and [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: I have two functions to come to the sql. for example - RunSql and GetSql. and I want that who only need to run the sql (without using the DataTable), will use in RunSql function.

Comment: Why one "who needs to run SQL" will even try to use `GetSql` function? And how that "only need X" is defined - permissions, something else? Sample and cleaner explanation of your actual problem may give you much better solution (and possible compile-time).

Comment: I have some sql procedures with very important info in the returned datatable, and I want to require to show this.

Comment: It is still beyond my understanding why one would call function that returns "very important info" and do not look at the result. I strongly suspect that you doing some sort of authentication scheme where DB contains "user X can access this row" and want caller to make permission check. If you doing something like this you simply should not expose raw SQL layer and check whatever "important information" yourself.

Answer (score 7):

One way to "require" the caller to get a value would be to use out:

```
public void MustUseReturnValueFN(out int result)
{
   result = 1;
}

static void Main()
{
   int returnValue;
   MustUseReturnValueFN(out returnValue);
   Console.WriteLine(returnValue) // this will print '1' to the console
}
```

Comment: Partly the correct answer, so upvoted. OP wants to force another method to be run when out value isnt used. You can only direct your users to do this by having proper documentation. Put a warning in GetSql to only use in the intended case, otherwise use RunSql. Maybe make it a bit 'harder' to use getSql by using the out variable, this will force them to actively perform an additional action to use GetSql, which in turn might make them read the method documentation pointing them to RunSql.

Comment: +1. in addition to @bastijn comment - or make API friendly and easy to write with desired usage and painful to be used in "wrong" way. I.e. move "wrong" version of method to some other class/require some special parameters ...